# How to Update Device Configuration using Google Cloud functions and MQTT bridge

Tags: mqtt, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

I am using the Google Cloud IoT with Pub/Sub.

I have a device reading sensor data and sending it to a topic in Pub/Sub.

I have a topic cloud function that is triggered by this message and I would like to have the device configuration updated, however I am unable to do so due to the following permission error.

index.js :

```
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {!Function} The callback function.
 */

  var google = require('googleapis');
    //var tt = google.urlshortener('v1');
  //console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(google.getAPIs()));
  var cloudiot = google.cloudiot('v1');

function handleDeviceGet(authClient, name, device_id, err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error with get device:', device_id);
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Got device:', device_id);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.config);

    var data2 = JSON.parse(
        Buffer.from(data.config.binaryData, 'base64').toString());
    console.log(data2);
    data2.on = !data2.on;
    console.log(data2);

    var request2 = {
        name: name,
        resource: {
            'versionToUpdate' : data.config.version,
            'binaryData' : Buffer(JSON.stringify(data2)).toString('base64')
        },
        auth: authClient
    };

    console.log('request2' + request2);

    var devices = cloudiot.projects.locations.registries.devices;
    devices.modifyCloudToDeviceConfig(request2, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error patching device:', device_id);
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Patched device:', device_id);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

const handleAuth = (device_id) => { 
    console.log(device_id);
    return (err, authClient) => {
      const project_id = 'animated-bonsai-195009';
      const cloud_region = 'us-central1';
      const registry_id = 'reg1';

      const name = `projects / ${project_id} /locations / ${cloud_region} /` +
            `registries / ${registry_id} /devices / ${device_id}`;

      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      }

      if (authClient.createScopedRequired &&
          authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
          authClient = authClient.createScoped(
              ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platforme']);
      }

      var request = {
          name: name,
          auth: authClient
      };

      // Get device version
      var devices = cloudiot.projects.locations.registries.devices;
      devices.get(request, (err, data) =>
                  handleDeviceGet(authClient, name, device_id, err, data));
  }
                                      };

exports.subscribe = (event, callback) => {

  // The Cloud Pub/Sub Message object.
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;

  // We're just going to log the message to prove that
  // it worked.

  var obj = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());

  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());
  console.log(event);
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(event));
  console.log(callback);

  let message = {
    "watter": 1
  };
  message = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(message));

  const req = {
        name: event.data.deviceId,
        resource: message
    };
    console.log(obj.deviceId);
  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(handleAuth(obj['deviceId']));

  // Don't forget to call the callback.
  callback();
};
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "sample-pubsub",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "googleapis": "25.0.0"
  }
}
```

Error:

[image: Output Logged error]

Comment: Please copy the text of error messages into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: I copied the useful part: `Error: A Not Found error was returned while attempting to retrieve an accesstoken for the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does not have any permission scopes specified.`

Comment: I am having the same problem with a cloud function: I'm trying to get the defaultCredentials in the Cloud Function environment, but I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- Check that you have enabled API access for the [Google Cloud IoT Core API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudiot.googleapis.com/) for the project used when creating the Google Cloud Function.
- Check that you have [enabled billing](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293499#enable-billing) for your project
- If you are deploying your Google Cloud Functions with `gcloud beta functions deploy` ... from the folder with your `.js` and `package.json` files, you may want to set the environment variables (`GCLOUD_PROJECT` and `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`) or use `gcloud auth application-default login` before deploying in case you have multiple Google Cloud projects and need to enable the API on the configured one.

**Update** [This community tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/iot-device-to-device) shows you how to do this - note that there have been some updates to Google Cloud Functions that require you to use a newer version of the Node JS client library as is done in [the NodeJS sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/manager/manager.js#L681-L719) and [as corrected in this PR](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/pull/500), note the [version of the client library in package.json](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/manager/package.json#L22).